# How to do a running sum in R with data.table (running window with one of the 2 end fixed)

Tags: r, data.table

I struggled to use just a data.table line to do this. I think this is trivial but did not find it.
I tried several things (running windows and other that I do not remember - I post this afterwards - sorry).

I want to sum up line by line the value of one variable and store it in another.
If I have `x` I want `y`:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| a | a |
| b | a+b |
| c | a+b+c |

Here an example, you will understand what I mean:
I do not know why exactly I need to use `mpg$displ` instead of `displ` maybe I need a `setkey()` ?

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
mpg <- data.table(mpg)
mpg[, new:= 0]
for(i in 2:nrow(mpg)) {
  mpg[i, new := mpg$displ[i]+mpg$new[i-1]]
}
mpg
```

Comment: cumsum you need

Comment: cumulative aggregate it is rather than running aggregate

Comment: cumulative special case of running is. `frollsum(x, n=seq_along(x), adaptive=TRUE)`

Comment: ```mpg[, new:= cumsum(mpg$displ)]```

Comment: @M--, we shouldn't need the `mpg$` there, I'd think just `mpg[, new := cumsum(displ)]`.

Comment: DorianGrv, note that your loop starts at 2, so `mpg[1,new]` is never really defined, which means your first row `new` value of `a` will remain `0`, the second row will be `b+0`.

Comment: @r2evans yea, at first I had it in `base` then changed it to `data.table` but forgot to take that out.